# How many transaction versions in Monero?

Tags: transaction-data

When I get information about transactions in block 1, using the RPC `/get_block`, I have one format of data. When I get information about transactions in block 2230000, I have a different format of data and I need to use `/get_transaction` to read more information.

So my question is, how many different formats of transaction does Monero have? What differences do they include? In what blocks these formats are accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many transaction versions in Monero? ... how many different formats of transaction does Monero have? What differences do they include? In what blocks these formats are accepted?

Two. **v1** (pre-RingCT, before block 1220517) and **v2** (RingCT, from block 1220517).

Comment: Thx my English not very good, but i try. But, how i understand, v1 an v2 did not affect for miners tx information? And all differents is hide amount of transactions?

Comment: There are only two tx versions/formats, v1 and v2, as answered. v1 transactions *are not* RingCT transactions, v2 transactions *are* RingCT transactions. Miner transactions do not hide the amount (CT) or mix the *input* (which is of type *gen*) in a Ring and thus are there is no difference for them between v1 and v2.

Comment: Thx, and last question, for rct, we have 5 types? Where i can read about differents?

Comment: "for rct, we have 5 types?" <- No. Assuming you're asking about tx *input types*, there are gen, script, scripthash and key input types, though only gen and key are used IIRC.